# Clarify on fields extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $k\subseteq K$ be a field extension. I should have this chain of implications:

> $K$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra $\Rightarrow$ $K$ is a finitely generated $k$-module $\Rightarrow$ $K$ is an algebraic extension of $k$.

The first is just the statement of Zariski's lemma, while I would justify the second in this way: if $K$ is generated by $n$ elements (as a $k$-module), for any $x\in K$ one has that the elements $1,a,a^2,\dots ,a^n $ are linearly dependent. My question is if for any of the two implications the converse holds, maybe in some (less generic but common) contexts.

Comment: A finitely generated module is also a finitely generated algebra. But the second converse is false: only finite algebraic extensions are finitely generated. A counter example is $\overline{\mathbb Q}/\mathbb Q$, which is algebraic by definition, but not finite.